# Apply Amazon EC2 t2.small Reserved Instance to t3.small

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I converted an Amazon EC2 `t2.small`  instance into a `t3.small` instance.

Can I apply the `t2.small` Reserved Instance to the  `t3.small` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Amazon EC2 Reserved Instance only applies to **a specific instance family** (eg T2 or T3).

If you purchased it as a **Convertible Reserved Instance**, then you can exchange the T2 Reserved Instance for a T3 Reserved Instance. (Actually, it's more like a refund and credit applied to the new Reserved Instance.)

If it is not 'Convertible', then you cannot change the Reserved Instance. However, you could *sell* the existing Reserved Instance on the Reserved Instance Marketplace and purchase a new one for T3.

See: [Standard vs. Convertible Offering Classes - Amazon EC2 Reserved Instances and Other AWS Service Reservation Models](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/cost-optimization-reservation-models/standard-vs.-convertible-offering-classes.html)

Comment: Thanks John! Will try to sell it